# Yii2: how include js bootstrap in one view?

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying include js bootstrap only on one view. How to do that? This does not work

```
$this->registerJsFile(yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset::className());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view file just place the below line on top:

```
\yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset::register($this);
```